# Assembly reference not getting updated in the silverlight 4.0 application project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, assemblies, reference

Point 1):

In one solution called CustomBehaviorsSolution, I have two projects - one is class library and another is silverlight class library project. The silverlight class library project has the class files which are 'linked' to the files of the first project. The solution compiles successfully.

Point 2):

I have another solution which has one silverlight application project and another desktop application project. The silverlight application project has the assembly refernce of the silverlight class library mentioned in Point 1 above. The desktop application project has the assembly reference to the class library mentioned in point 1 above.

Now, when I modify or add any class to the project mentioned in point 1 above and update their references in the projects in the solution 2; I experienced some weird behavior.

- The desktop application project gets the new changes from the referred assembly whereas the SILVERLIGHT application project does not get the same changes from the referred assembly.

In ILDASM i saw the referred assemblies of point 1 above and they are alright. The problem is that the silverlight application project is not reading the updations from the assembly reference.

Can someone please help?

(I have been removing and then adding the assembly references.)

I'm using VS 2010 and Silverlight 4.0. (After ensuring almost everything, now I think that it might be a bug in VS 2010 or SL 4.0 ! Possible?

Comment: I had the same problem twice now. I never got any answer or solution for these problems. The first time this problem occurred, I reformatted my PC because I blamed my TuneUp reg cleaner doing some nasty cleaning in my registry. Now I'm having the same problem.. and I am hoping I could get an answer. This maybe a VS 2010 bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the new solution altogether (mentioned in point 2) and then added necessary assembly references and now everything is fine.

It seems that the previous solution was corrupted due to some reason.